# Uploading Using Javascript and Reconstruct using Java on the server side

Tags: java, javascript, file-upload

I am doing a short program which upload file in slices on the client side using Javascript in chunks and reconstruct it on the server side using Java.

The client side code is as follows:

```
function chunkUpload(file) {
    var size = file.size;
    var chunkSize = 1048576;
    var nextChunkStart = 0;

    while(nextChunkStart < size) {
        var chunkEnd;
        if(nextChunkStart + chunkSize > size) {
            chunkEnd = size;
        }else{
            chunkEnd = nextChunkStart + chunkSize;
        }

        uploadSlice(file, nextChunkStart, chunkEnd);
        nextChunkStart = chunkEnd;
    }
}

function uploadSlice(file, startIndex, stopIndex) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/upload", false);

        reader.onload = function(evt) {
            var contents = evt.target.result;
            xhr.send(contents);
        };

        var blob = file.slice(startIndex, stopIndex);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
```

On the server side, I have the code:

```
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UploadServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = req.getInputStream();
        try {
            writeToDisk(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    private void writeToDisk(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/Users/myself/uploaded.jpg", true);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the file I got on the server side does not reassembles the file I uploaded. Actually, a file I was trying to upload is only 1.5M in size but on the server side it is 2.3M in size.

What did I do wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: Looks ok. Can you try using copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, int bufferSize) or copyLarge

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It produces the same result.

Comment: Another idea, you can use browser Firefox and a plugin Firebug to debug how many requests are coming from your browser to backend. Try this. Just an idea for debugging.